# Yii2 Weird Class not found with Empty name

Tags: php, rest, yii2

May perfectly understand that a Class 'xxx' is not found.

But there i got an empty className as pasted below, happening in the context of a simple REST auth

```
PHP Fatal Error
Class '' not found

yii\base\ErrorException
/home/genie/yii-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/IndexAction.php
```

Some code below, but why that guy throws an empty Classname like this ????

Controller that handles the login (User model implements the identityInterface :

```html
<?php
namespace api\controllers;
use yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use common\models\User;

class RestController extends ActiveController
{

 public $modelClass = '';
 // public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';

 public function behaviors()
 {
 $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
 $behaviors['verbs'] = [
 'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
 'actions' => [
 'index' => ['get', 'head'],
 ],
 ];

 $behaviors['access'] = [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'only' => ['index'],
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['index'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
];




$behaviors['authenticator'] = [

 'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::className(),

 'auth' => function ($username, $password) {

     $user = \common\models\User::findByUsername($username);

     if ($user ) {


   $pass = \common\models\User::validatePassword($password);

   if($pass)
    return $user;

     }

 }

];

 return $behaviors;
 }



}
```

Comment: The error is clear .. you have not  the class (empty string) but why you are assign empty string  to $modelClass ?

Comment: Indeed :) so obvious. u made my day